# Check Presence of Object Failing - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup a 'add to cart' button, where after user has added product to a cart, the button becomes disabled unless the product is removed from the cart.

I'm trying `.present?` but it seems to ignore this whether the product is already in the cart or not.  Even if my cart is completely empty, it still has shows the disabled button.

Any clues how I fix this?

View (Product show):

```
 <% if @product.price.present? %>
   <% if !@product.line_items.present? %>
       <%= form_for @line_item do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id %>                                                       
          <%= f.submit "Add to cart" %>
       <% end %>
  <% else %>
      <%= button_to "Added to cart", "", class: "", disabled: true %>           
  <% end %>                               
<% end %>
```

Product Controller:

```
class ProductController < InheritedResources::Base
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show]

    def show
        @line_item = current_order.line_items.new
    end

    def set_product
      @product = Product.find_by(product_number: params[:product_number])
    end

end
```

Models

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items
  belongs_to :user, optional: true


end
```

Line Items Model

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, optional: true
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  belongs_to :service, optional: true
end
```

Service Model

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items
end
```

Comment: Does this portion of product show page gets reloaded after user adds the product to cart? If not, you will get `@product.line_items.blank?` => `true` because it was blank initially.

Comment: Why don't you check if `current_order.line_items` includes the product?

Comment: `current_order.line_items.new` should also be `current_order.line_items.build` (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to check if the product is already in the cart.

```
def show
  @line_item = current_order.line_items.new
  @product_already_in_the_cart = current_order.line_items.pluck(:product_id).include? @product.id
end
```

Then use `@product_already_in_the_cart` for the if statement in view.

```
unless @product_already_in_the_cart
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Marked as correct as it's the more elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are viewing LineItem from the Product side. So this means that if there is any LineItem for a product, it will disable the button. So if User A has already ordered a Product, the button will be hidden for everyone!

You need to change the conditional:

```
 <% if @product.price.present? %>
   <% if @line_item.where(product: @product).empty? %>
       <%= form_for @line_item do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: @product.id %>                                                       
          <%= f.submit "Add to cart" %>
       <% end %>
  <% else %>
      <%= button_to "Added to cart", "", class: "", disabled: true %>           
  <% end %>                               
<% end %>
```

In general, I do feel this is a bit to much logic for a view, but that might be a different discussion.